# Como abrir meu componente 404 em caso de erro sem mudar a URL em Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, http-status-404, vue-router

Como faço para abrir meu componente "NotFound", dentro de outro componente, usando beforeRouteEnter, sem mudar a url?

> Criei uma rota dinâmica, e uma * para abrir o "NotFound" em todos os outros casos.

```
{

    path: '/work/:id',
    name: 'work',
    component: () => import( './views/Work.vue' )

},

{

    path: '*',
    name: 'NotFound',
    component: () => import( './views/NotFound.vue' )

}
```

> Dentro do componente Work.vue faço uma verificação para saber se o id existe no json estático. Se não existir chama o "NotFound"

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
        vm.item = json.find(item => item.id == vm.$route.params.id)

        if(!vm.item) {
            next({name: NotFound})
        }

    })
}
```

Ele chama o "NotFound" (isto é, aparece a mensagem que criei neste componente), o problema é que a url muda de site.com.br/work/id-nao-existente para a raiz, isto é www.site.com.br. Eu gostaria que a url não fosse alterada.

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar isso, acredito que deve funcionar:

```
  {
    path: '/404',
    name: 'notFound.index',
    component: () => import( './views/NotFound.vue' ),
  },
  { path: '*', redirect: '/404' },
```

Comment: agradeço a resposta, mas no caso eu não quero redirecionar os erros para a rota /404. gostaria que permanecesse a url com o erro na página.

Comment: Entendi, você tem duas opções ao meu ver utilizar [alias](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#redirect) ou utilizar [history.replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/History_API#O_m%C3%A9todo_replaceState())... Eu recomendaria tentar o alias primeiramente, acredito que deve funcionar :)